# Componentizing markup with relative js and css

Tags: components, conditional-statements, templating

I've been thinking of a way to include components of markup in a modular fashion. For example if I were to include a slider I would have to include the relevant css and JS for it to function correctly. Is there any known method of including these as one component?

```
<div> {{slider}} </div>
```

{{slider}} then would import slider.html, slider.css and slider.js but to their respective directories. css/slider.css and js/slider.js

Is this possible given our current array of production tools?